# DOSBox ConEmu integration

Tags: windows, conemu, dosbox

Is it possible to use ConEmu as a terminal for the DOSBox console? If so, how?

I followed the instructions from the [ConEmu project site](https://conemu.github.io/en/DosBox.html):

- I installed DOSBox to `C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu\DosBox`
- I mounted my C drive (with matching drive letter) in DosBox.conf
- The "DosBox" integration checkbox in the ConEmu settings is checked

However, there is still no DOSBox console/task available. When I start DOSBox and attach it to ConEmu, the status window gets attached instead of the DOS console.

I would like to use the DOSBox console from within ConEmu. Is that possible? I don't understand exactly what's going on here, so apart from practical answers (which I'm primarily interested in) any background explanation is also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DosBox is not a "console". It creates an external GUI window with **fixed** size. There is no sense to embed this fixed sized [ChildGui](https://conemu.github.io/en/ChildGui.html) because the behavior would be unexpected on ConEmu resize.

DosBox integration means that you may start DOS applications directly from (for example) cmd.exe running in the ConEmu console. This DOS application will then start in a DosBox window outside of ConEmu. Same as if you run "calc" from the cmd console.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how does ConEmu determine if an executable is a DOS application?

Comment: By exe header of course.